# How to pick MOSFETs and drivers for FPGA BLDC driver?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, mosfet-driver

I am building a Brushless DC Motor driver based on an FPGA.
I need to pick the transistors and drivers.
Do I need an IC driver or can I use smaller transistors?
The motor runs on 15A/16V.
I am estimating 50kHz switching frequency.
To be able to use them without cooling i calculated a maximum Drain-Source resistance of about 4mOhm.
CSD17506Q5A seems to fit the requirements. Is this a good choice? How should I drive it?
Do I need external diodes?

Comment: Look at what are call H-bridge drivers. This is good starting point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Driving the ~1.5nF input capacitance of the specified MOSFET might be more than you could muster from an FPGA. With 50 kHz switching, the period is 20 us and you'll want switching times to be less than (say) 5% of this period (to maintain efficiency) and there are two switching events in that time so, you want to be able to charge (or discharge) the gate in about 500 ns.

I = c dv/dt and if your dv/dt is (say 3V/500ns) 6 MV/sec, I estimate the current injected needs to be 9mA but the potentially bigger problem is with the mosfet - it needs more gate voltage: -

[image]

With a gate-source voltage of 4V, the volt drop at 15A is about 0.07 volts - that's an equivalent on resistance of 4.7 milli ohms - can you provide a 4V drive is my big concern?

My next concern is that you probably haven't figured out how to drive the transistors at the top of the H bridge - these cannot be easily driven from an FPGA - you need a specialist driver chip. Probably something like this: -

[image]

The chip above is an ISL83202 but plenty of folk make similar offerings like this one from IR: -

[image]

So, do a bit more digging around and find the driver that suits your logic levels and the mosfets you want to use.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. So you think the transistor i chose is OK for the application? The problem is I need to drive 12 of those, and the DRV8302DCA that seems ideal is really too expensive. Can't I use one lower voltage transistor between the gate of each and GND and one between the gate and VCC for driving?

Comment: The transistor is OK but you can't easily drive the top transistor this way because the gate has to rise higher than source to turn it on AND, simultaneously you want the source to be virtually at the drain voltage - this means you have to drive the gate ABOVE the drain voltage - this is what the chips in my answer do - they do it by stealing a little power from the output and bootstrapping a higher-than-drain voltage that can be used to power the gate thus ensuring the TOP mosfet is "hard-conducting". Or you use slower and higher resistance P channel mosfets in the top position.

Comment: Can I use a boost converter to create a higher voltage rail and use BJTs to drive the gates then?

Comment: Maybe you could use PMOS on the top, since it is only a 16V rail. There are PMOS parts that have low Rds and can withstand 20V Vgs.

Comment: You can use a boost converter, but the total voltage will exceed 20V so you need extra circuitry to keep Gate-Source voltage below 20V.  Most commercial controllers (even cheap ones) use an integrated driver like IR2103, NCP5104 etc. which reduces parts count and may even be cheaper.

Comment: I've explained how to drive it and @Bruce has hinted that using a driver may in fact be the cheaper solution (which I agree).

Comment: Could you provide an example driver that would work in this scenario?

Comment: Would FAN7888MX be a good choice?

Comment: I think you did a good job selecting the CSD17506Q5A so I trust you to find a replacement/equivalent. Example drivers are given in my answer and what @Bruce said. Plus there are others at Linear technology. You need to think about this question and whether there are likely to be other answers that might influence you and wait.... Or formally accept this answer as the small price to pay for knowledge. You can always ask a new question as you develop your ideas.